# How to add a new options to gpg command line

Tags: command-line

When I use gpg to encrypt files, I can use *-c*, or *--symmetric*, and also *-a* for armor.

> -c, --symmetric     encryption only with symmetric cipher
>   -a, --armor           create ascii armored output

How can I add *-g*, so that the command would be `gpg -c -g AES25`, instead of `gpg -c --cipher-algo AES25`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly with `gpg`.  The code which is compiled to make `gpg` supports certain command line options, and some of those have aliases, but it's not something you change directly.

You could write a script/wrapper for `gpg` (say, call it `my-gpg`) which took one set of command line options and then converted them into the options `gpg` expects.

So you could write the script, and then use,

```
my-gpg -c -g AES25
```

and the script would in turn run

```
gpg -c -cipher-algo AES25
```

But you'd need to implement that yourself.  You could use a simple bash alias to achieve the same thing as well.

Comment: Yep, an alias or some other similar process (personally, I consider aliases the same as scripts).

Comment: @rezx don't forget to mark answers that help as Answered.